# Android Espresso: test dynamically created buttons that do not have IDs assigned

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have multiple buttons that are created dynamically in a for loop and are not having an ID. I need to do automation testing on those buttons. How can I do this with Espresso? This is the for loop that creates the various buttons:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; i++) {
            TableRow.LayoutParams vl = new TableRow.LayoutParams(30,30);
            Button b = new Button(context);
            b.setId(((blockNumber * 10000)+i));
            //b.setHint(i);
            //b.setHint(blockNumber);
    //      double selectedGrade = 0;
    //      if(FinalSurvey.multi[blockNumber][i] != 0){
    //          selectedGrade = FinalSurvey.multi[blockNumber][i];
    //      }
    //      final int makeHighlight = selectedGrade;
            b.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a));
            b.setAlpha(1.0f);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ViewsAdding va = new ViewsAdding();
                    va.showGrades(context, v, grades);
                    view = v;
                    maincontext = context;
                }
            });

            if(i%5 == 0){
                innerLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
                innerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                innerLayout.setLayoutParams(innerparams);
                vl.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
                b.setLayoutParams(vl);
                innerLayout.addView(b);
                if(i == numberOfSamples-1){
                    mainLinearLayout.addView(innerLayout);
                }
                b = null;
            }else if (i%5 ==1) {
                vl.setMargins(22, 5, 5, 5);
                b.setLayoutParams(vl);
                innerLayout.addView(b);
                if(i == numberOfSamples-1){
                    mainLinearLayout.addView(innerLayout);
                }
                b = null;
            }else if (i%5 ==2) {
                vl.setMargins(25, 5, 5, 5);
                b.setLayoutParams(vl);
                innerLayout.addView(b);
                mainLinearLayout.addView(innerLayout);
                b = null;
            }else if (i%5 ==3) {
                innerLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
                innerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                innerLayout.setLayoutParams(innerparams);
                vl.setMargins(35, 5, 5, 5);
                b.setLayoutParams(vl);
                innerLayout.addView(b);
                if(i == numberOfSamples-1){
                    mainLinearLayout.addView(innerLayout);
                }
                b = null;
            }else{
                vl.setMargins(30, 5, 5, 5);
                b.setLayoutParams(vl);
                innerLayout.addView(b);
                mainLinearLayout.addView(innerLayout);
                b = null;
            }
        }
        return mainLinearLayout;
    }
```

Comment: what have you tried already? where exactly are you stuck? one way i could think of is to assign a tag to the button and then get it in the test via this tag.

Comment: Button b = new Button(context);   i need to do automation test without using id  so this button i have written in forloop i m getting so many button .. i need to click one by one as automation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code where you create the buttons add a tag to the button depending on the case:

```
button.setTag("someTag");
```

so in your case you could do it in your if clauses:

```
       if(i%5 == 0){
            ...
            b.setTag("case0-" + i);
            ...
        }else if (i%5 ==1) {
            ...
            b.setTag("case1-" + i);
            ...
        }
        ...
```

and then in your test you can get the buttons with this or click it:

```
onView(allOf(withTagValue(is((Object) "case0-0")), isDisplayed())).perform(click());
onView(allOf(withTagValue(is((Object) "case0-0")), isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

you can also replace the "case0-0" string with a loop to regenerate the tags

Comment: i have idded above code . but i have get some exception.      android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with tag value: is "case0-0"' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

Comment: this means you have multiple buttons that have the same tag. you have to make sure the tag you generate for the buttons is unique. also add the isDisplayed() check to just look for views that are currently displayed, i updated the answer above

Comment: See above i have mensioned code is having .. tableLayout inside button it is possible to do test for table row

Comment: sorry i don't understand where your exact problem is now? is the test failing? (at the first button check or somewhere else?) 
if the buttons are not visible you would have to scroll to them first before you can click them

Comment: again i have update my entire class code. i need to do test for using prsticular postion clicking.. that code having one button inside create screen

Comment: but that button is in for loop i need to do automation for multple button with the perticular postion

Comment: i have update the image also that perticular image i need to select and do unit test

Comment: Hello, @stamanuel same thing is happened with me but the component is the radio button which dynamically added in radio group I was tried using your given answered way but it's not working.
How to solve this problem. This way the code created ->

I have taken one activity inside that open one fragment and inside the fragment, I was added all the radio button in the radio group programmatically with tag.